# Битрикс: путь для сохранения файла

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет!
Народ, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно настроить папку для сохранения файлов в свойстве инфоблока?

Например есть какой то инфоблок. В нём есть свойство типа "Файл". Когда я в это свойство добавляю например PDF-файл, то он загружается по пути:

/upload/iblock/<набор_букв_и_цифр>/Имя_файла

Так вот, где в Битриксе можно задать папку по-умолчанию для сохранения файлов инфоблока?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Такое поведение не предусмотрено для стандартного типа поля файл.
Чем обусловлена такая необходимость?
Получить путь к файлу можно получить с помощью

```
CFile::GetPath($value);
```

Для реализации отдельной папки инфоблока можно использовать событие [OnFileSave](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/events/index.php) в котором проверять необходимость подмены пути файла через параметры запроса или сессии.

Answer (score 0):

Для отдельного инфоблока нельзя поменять. Можно поменять для всего сайта: Настройки - Настройки модулей - Главный модуль - Папка по умолчанию для хранения файлов.

[image]